# How to find first rows with specific condition after rows with another specific condition

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have dataframe of football game events like this. And I would like to find and mark first rows with type "Pass | Take on" which followed after events with condition "yes" in "is_seq_end".

Rows with id 5 and 10 matches this criteria in my example.

| id | type | is_seq_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dispossessed | yes |
| 2 | Defensive | no |
| 3 | Other | no |
| 4 | Defensive | no |
| 5 | Pass | no |
| 6 | Pass | no |
| 7 | Dispossessed | yes |
| 8 | Defensive | no |
| 9 | Other | no |
| 10 | Take on | no |

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:10, type = c("Dispossessed", "Defensive", 
"Other", "Defensive", "Pass", "Pass", "Dispossessed", "Defensive", 
"Other", "Take on"), is_seq_end = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", 
"no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

So desired output

| id | type | is_seq_end | is_seq_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dispossessed | yes | no |
| 2 | Defensive | no | no |
| 3 | Other | no | no |
| 4 | Defensive | no | no |
| 5 | Pass | no | yes |
| 6 | Pass | no | no |
| 7 | Dispossessed | yes | no |
| 8 | Defensive | no | no |
| 9 | Other | no | no |
| 10 | Take on | no | yes |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df |>
  mutate(is_seq_end = is_seq_end == "yes",
        group = cumsum(is_seq_end))|>
  mutate(is_seq_start = cumsum(str_detect(type, "Pass|Take on")) == 1 & lag(str_detect(type, "Pass|Take on"), default = FALSE) == 0, .by = group)
```

Comment: don't encode bools as strings. true statements should be TRUE, not "TRUE", or "yes" or something else

Comment: Sorry, I've got an error "Can't supply `.by` when `.data` is a grouped data frame".

Comment: This message indicates your data frame is already grouped. If you call `group_by()` before this `mutate()` you should call `ungroup()` before `mutate`. If the grouping is on the same variable in `mutate` (that is, `group`), then you can simply delete the `group_by` function.

Comment: what @Seth said. You forgot to ungroup() somewhere

Comment: @Mark could you explain please what "cumsum" actually do in this case? Why can't we do this like that 

df |>
  mutate(is_seq_end = is_seq_end == "yes",
        group = cumsum(is_seq_end))|>
  mutate(is_seq_start = (str_detect(type, "Pass|Take on")) == 1 & lag(str_detect(type, "Pass|Take on"), default = FALSE) == 0, .by = group)

Comment: @Delopera think about this example: `df <- data.frame(
    id = 1:5,
    type = c("Dispossessed", "Pass", "Other", "Pass", "Dispossessed"),
    is_seq_end = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes"))`

Comment: you want to capture the *first* example of a take on or pass during a group. Just checking the previous one doesn't cut it, because it could be that it occurred ten rows ago for all I know

Comment: btw, in general, in general I'd recommend using `.by = group` like in my answer, instead of `group_by(group)`, as it avoids you having to remember to ungroup, and so avoids the problem you faced earlier

Comment: @Mark thanks for cleared explanations and advise. It is really helpful.

Comment: @Delopera if you want to mark it solved, that would be great! :-)

Comment: @Delopera as I've answered two of your questions so far, and you haven't marked either as correct. Marking things as correct acknowledges the work that went into the answer and shows in some way your thankfulness!

Comment: @Mark I'm sorry. I've marked your solution above as accepted. Is it any way to mark your answers in comments as correct? Sorry, it seems I'm not fully familiar with Statckoverflow rules. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: that's okay! I'm sorry for being a bit brusk, sometimes people disappear when they get what they want -.-